# Hier encore, tout allait bien

Tags: adverbes

> **Encore** hier, tout allait bien.
>
> Hier **encore**, tout allait bien.

Est-ce que la deuxième phrase est plus belle vu la chanson de Charles Aznavour, *Hier encore*  ?

> Hier **encore**, j'avais vingt ans, je caressais le temps...

Comment: Cette attitude de fermer les questions (sans y répondre) est lassante...

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est pas une question de beauté mais de sens:

`Hier encore` -> Une situation valable jusqu'à hier mais maintenant terminée "Hier encore j'avais 39 de fièvre" "Hier encore je l'ai croisé (= sous-entendu maintenant je ne le croiserai plus/il est décédé/etc. ...)"

`Encore hier` -> Un événement s'est produit encore une fois hier et on veut insister sur la répétition de ces événements "Encore hier j'ai été verbalisé" "Encore hier je l'ai croisé (= sentiment d'exaspération)"

Comment: « Hier encore » peut avoir les deux sens. Je n'arrive pas à trouver d'exemple où je dirais « encore hier » en début de phrase. « J'ai encore été verbalisé hier » ou « hier, j'ai encore été verbalisé », ou « Hier encore je fus verbalisé » dans un langage très soutenu.

Comment: Juste un exemple: https://www.15heures.com/photos/p/43052/ Ici aussi: https://www.mondedestars.com/potins/encore-hier-celine-est-sortie-avec-son-compagnon

Comment: Merci. Quelqu'un m'a dit (2 personnes) que "hier encore" est plus idiomatique, mais que "encore hier" est aussi compréhensible et correct. Mais une autre personne a dit que "encore hier" s'emploie surtout dans des phrases comme _elle est venue encore hier (elle vient tout les jours)_